# Why, when calculating rise time, do we use 2.2·τ? (RC low-pass circuit)

Tags: digital-communications, electrolytic-capacitor

I am just trying to understand why we use 2.2·τ when calculate the rise time. I can't find a derivation anywhere, I don't understand where this 2.2 comes from.

Answer (score 8):

For charging:

$$V(t) = V_0(1 - e^{-t/\tau})$$

Lets say rise time 10% to 90% of V<sub>0</sub>. So in this equation put: $$V(t) = 0.1 \cdot V_0$$ 
and find \$t_1\$. Similarly put: $$V(t) = 0.9 \cdot V_0$$ and find \$t_2\$. You'll get: $$rise time = t_2-t_1 = 2.2 \tau$$

Comment: Supplementing the above answer we have for the rise time (defined between 10% and 90% of the final value): Tr=tau*(ln0.9-ln0.1).

Comment: Thank you! that was the part i failed to do! (ln0.9-ln0.1) = 2.197 :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard formula of Vc=A+Be-(T/Tau) you solve for 90% and 10% and get T90%=-Tau*ln(0.1)=Tau*2.3026 & T10%=-Tau*ln(0.9)=0.1054 and subtracting T10% from T90% you get Trise=2.1972*Tau or about 2.2*Tau; where Tau=R*C.

Answer (score 2):

[image: RC Circuit]

The equation below describes the circuit’s behaviour:
$$I=C\frac{dV_{out}}{dt}=\frac{V_s-V_{out}}{R}\tag{1}$$

where:

- \$V_s\$ is the source voltage (i.e. the voltage applied to the circuit),
- \$V_{out}\$ is the output voltage of the circuit (i.e. the voltage level you want to reach)

Solving the above differential equation for \$V_{out}\$ over time yields:

$$V_{out}(t)=V_s(1-e^{-t/RC})\tag2$$

Which can be turned around to solve for \$t\$ given a desired \$V_{out}\$:

$$t=\ln{\left(\frac{V_s}{V_s-V_{out}}\right)}\cdot{RC}\tag{3}$$
The 10% to 90% risetime is then $$t_{rise}=t_{90\%}-t_{10\%}\tag{4}$$
That is:
$$\begin{align}
t_{90\%}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-0.9}\right)RC=
\ln{10}\cdot{RC}\approx2.303\cdot{RC}\\
t_{10\%}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-0.1}\right)RC=\ln{1.1}\cdot{RC}\approx0.105\cdot{RC}
\end{align}$$
Then, finally, $$t_{rise}=(2.303-0.105){RC}\approx2.2{RC}\tag5$$